# Testing a lot of related entities with junit

Tags: java, mysql, junit

Having relation like this
[image]

how should I test my repositories.

Testing separate filmRepo and personRepo doesn't make a lot of sense if I keep relation like that.
Should I separate two "main" entities and don't bind them or break the relationship.

If I keep the relationship like that getting a film will also bring all the data related including all information about persons related to this film entity (which is what I want most of the time).

How will this affect the speed if there will be more row and more related entities?

If there's another better approach can you point me the link please.

Thanks.